# Need to select a file and Save it in given folder in android

Tags: android, android-file

> According to my code that I can select a file after that how can I save that selected file in given directory?
>   Here I captured Uri but I could not save that audio file in Specific folder.
>   Where can be the issue?Any mistake which I have done while writing outputStream?

```
public class Upload extends AppCompatActivity {
    File folder;

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

        /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity
         * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
        folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Audios");
        File folder1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/");
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            folder.mkdir();
        }
        for (File f : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (f.isFile()) {
                String name = f.getName();
                // System.out.print(name);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            // Do your stuff
        }
        Intent intent_upload = new Intent();
        intent_upload.setType("audio/*");
        intent_upload.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent_upload, 1);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
                //the selected audio.

                Uri uri = data.getData();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), uri.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                File test = new File(uri.getPath());
                try {
                    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(test);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(folder, true);
                    int bufferSize = 1024;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                    int len = 0;
                    while ((len = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not "select a file". It allows the user to choose a piece of content.

In `onActivityResult()`, if the result code is `RESULT_OK`, the `Intent` will have a `Uri` pointing to the selected piece of content. Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on that content. From there, do what you need to do, such as open a `FileOutputStream` to some file and then copy the bytes from the `InputStream` to the `OutputStream`.

BTW, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` does not take a `Uri` as input. Replace `setDataAndType()` with `setType()`.

Comment: I edited my question.Still I could not save file .Thank you for the solution.